# I want to update my stock quantity keeping along the previous quantity.

Tags: c#, sql, .net, logic, inventory-management

I want to update my stock quantity keeping along the previous stock status. I need to update the previous data by adding or lessening it depending upon the inward or outward transaction. I am not getting the stock updated in the currentstock table.
//This is the start of Problem segment

```
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select stock from currentstock where itemname=@a", con);
        con.Open();
        int x=0;
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a",comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
             x = dr.GetInt16(2);
        }
        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            x = x + Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text);
        }
        else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
        {
            x = x - Convert.ToInt16(textBox2.Text);
        }
            con.Close();



        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("update currentstock set stock=@a where itemname=@b",con);
        con.Open();
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", x);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

// This is the end of the problem segment

Comment: so where is the problem coming?

Comment: x = x + Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text);

x = x - Convert.ToInt16(textBox2.Text);
I think these two statements are not getting executed.

Comment: please explain what problem are you facing on which line and what error or exception if any coming,

Comment: The changes are expected to be made in the currentstock table but the program even after the complete execution is not reflecting any changes in the database.

Comment: are you sure values that are passed are different from the ones there ins table row

Comment: bebug and see it goes in if of radiobutton checke?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly please dont use values directly from user inputs when talking to your sql tables (see [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)). Use stored procedures.

I would expect that the value you are getting back from the combo box is not a valid value in the itemname column of your table.

Comment: It is a valid value and the program on debugging is not showing any error. The combo box is giving back a value which is in string format and Im using the item name as a nvarchar type in SQL table..